# Pattern Matching Strings that End in Varying Non-Printed Char's

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching

This is probably very simple to accomplish but I cannot figure out the most elegant and simplistic way of producing my desired results.  Basically, a text file is sent as input to my program.  All of the strings in this file are separated by carriage returns (`\r`), new line feeds (`\n`), or a combination of the two.

Right now, my function is the following

```
local function file_Parse(input)
    local inputTbl = {}
    if input then
        for lines in input:gmatch("%g*%G*") do
            lines = lines:gsub("\r\n", "")
            table.insert(inputTbl, #inputTbl + 1, lines)
        end
    end
    return inputTbl
end
```

Now this is very basic.  The input received will look something similar to the following:

`DFEIJ-SDFA\r\nDAFK-DAFDAFEA\r\nDKLAJFDAKJFE-DFAKJ\r\n` for example.  Now please keep in mind that I've placed `\r\n` between the strings I want.  But sometimes, I may have a mixture of the carriage return and line feeds, in varying order or missing one of the two, randomly between the strings I want.  This is my issue.

Now it works in the function I've provided above, but for me to have to enter `lines = lines:gsub("\r\n","")` into this at all is really bothering me.  I feel that I should be able to take care of it in the start of my for loop within the `lines:gmatch("%g*%G*")` line and automatically not capture those non-printable characters.  But I can't figure out for the life of me the best way to check if `\r`, `\n`, or both `\r\n` (or `\n\r`) is matched, only grab the printable characters and forget the non-printable ones.

I've tried to attempt varying methods and for the most part, it appears to not capture `lines` in my for loop and enter them into the table.  I've tried some of the following:

`("(%g*%G*)[\r\n]")`

`("(%g*%G*)[\r*\n*]")`

`("(%g*%G*)[\r-\n-]")`

`("(%g*%G*)[\r?\n?]")`

`("(%g*%G*)[%c]")`

`("(%g*%G*)[%c-]")`

`("(%g*%G*)[%c+]")`

I've read both http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial and http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1 resources but am failing to properly grab all printable characters and not the non-printable characters.  I'd appreciate some advice to help me understand what I am doing wrong and the answer to the approach I'm looking for?

Comment: `for lines in input:gmatch("%g+") do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As EgorSkriptunoff said in the comment, using `%g` should do what you want, but you need to keep in mind that it doesn't capture any spaces, so if your lines include a mix of printable and space characters, you need to use something like this:

```
for lines in input:gmatch("[%g ]+") do
```

This produces the following three lines on the input you shown:

```
DFEIJ-SDFA
DAFK-DAFDAFEA
DKLAJFDAKJFE-DFAKJ
```

Comment: Wow.... did I botch this one!  haha.  I would have given Egor a point for the help but obviously can not.  My apologies.  Thank you both for your help and I appreciate the clarification, Paul.